# variable names are not exported to CSV from R

Tags: r

I am trying to generate the frequency table for all the variables in a dataframe. When i export the tables to CSV from R the variable names are not exported to CSV however when viewed in R console the tables appear with variable name. So could anyone help me in getting the variable names to CSV.

```
data <- read.spss("Test.sav", use.value.labels = TRUE, to.data.frame = TRUE)
Crossdata <- lapply(data, function(x) xtabs(~x+data$TREND)) 
data = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, Crossdata))
write.csv(data, file = "data.csv")
```

Comment: CSV files are format free!!! If you want to save with formats, you would need to save your file as an excel document.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by "not formatted properly". i.e. how is it formatted, and how is it different from what you expected (with an example). Also state what you've tried

Answer (score 1):

try this block of code when writing `.csv` file using write.csv()`:

```
df <- write.csv("something.csv",col.names = TRUE,...)
```

let me know if this works.

Comment: Please share/display your code with reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

That is because there is two formats of CSV, the normal one (,) and the variant used in countries that use a comma as decimal point (;) so maybe you are using a program who doesnt format CSVs the normal way